# git-lfs INSTALLATION ERROR : Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: linux, git, github, embedded-linux, git-lfs

I am working on Jetson nano platform `ARMv8 Processor rev 1 (v8l) × 4`.
I downloaded and extracted the binary from  https://git-lfs.github.com/

```
git-lfs-linux-amd64-v2.11.0.tar.gz
```

Trying to install from the install.sh script provided in the download package on Debian/sid:

```
sudo bash -x install.sh
```

I get the following  and the error:

```
+ set -eu
+ prefix=/usr/local
+ '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
+ '[' '' '!=' '' ']'
+ mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
+ rm -rf /usr/local/bin/git-lfs
++ dirname install.sh
+ pushd .
+ for g in git*
+ install git-lfs /usr/local/bin/git-lfs
+ popd
+ PATH+=:/usr/local/bin
+ git lfs install
/usr/local/bin/git-lfs: 1: /usr/local/bin/git-lfs: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
```

The git version`git version 2.17.1`

```
$ git lfs help
/usr/local/bin/git-lfs: 1: /usr/local/bin/git-lfs: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding for others if they have this issue. Once this is done you will need to install git flow with following command:
`sudo apt-get install git-flow`.
then you need to set the file you want git lfs to manage: `git lfs track "*.yyyy"`. next step make sure `.gitattribute` is tracked `git add .gitattributes`.

Just commit and push to GitHub as you normally would. You may need to do the following for lfs files =>retroactively migrate existing large files into Git LFS in order to decrease the size of your Git push  :`git lfs migrate import --include="*.onnx"`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am progressing. Here is what I did and was able to install git-lfs

I  have `git-lfs` installed in `/usr/local/bin/git-lfs`.

I read that this  path is not maintained by APT. I remove it  with

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/git-lfs
```

and I applied package reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git-lfs
```